# Why are the 'multipolygons' in my export of geometry data to CSV in QGIS incomplete?

Tags: gis, export-to-csv, qgis

I used the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435254/is-it-possible-to-export-geometry-data-from-a-shapefile-to-csv-from-qgis#:%7E:text=5-,You%20can%20simply%20right%2Dclick%20the%20layer%20entry%20in%20QGIS,file%20formats%20to%20choose%20from.) to successfully export geometry data to CSV in QGIS. However, when I had a look at the data, the geometry data (multipolygons in my case) of the records were incomplete. The multipolygons stopped after x amount of characters.
Is there a limit on the max length of a geometry attribute? Is it possible to change this?

I already had a look at different settings, but none seem appropriate for this issue.

Comment: Please show an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same issue & is searching for an answer:
The problem lies in CSV. The maximum number of characters is 32,767, so if your polygon / multipolygon exceeds that, you will have this issue.